# How to add elements to existing HTML using DomDocument?

Tags: php, html, dom

I have the following select drop-down

```
<select name="set_login_redirect" id="set_login_redirect">
    <option value="dashboard">WordPress Dashboard</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="1881">Activate</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="2109">Affiliate Area</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="429">Cart</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="430">Checkout</option>
</select>
```

How do I use the PHP `DomDocument` class to add a new `option` element to the `select` drop-down.

For example, I want to add the code below to the HTML above.

How can it be done?

```
<option class="level-0" value="27">The Word</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get an answer so wrote a PHP function with some dirty regex to solve it.

```
/**
 * Append an option to a select dropdown
 *
 * @param string $option option to add
 * @param string $select select dropdown
 *
 * @return string
 */
function pp_append_option_to_select($option, $select) {
    $regex = "/<select ([^<]*)>/";

    preg_match($regex, $select, $matches);
    $select_attr = $matches[1];

    $a = preg_split($regex, $select);

    $join = '<select ' . $select_attr . '>' . "\r\n";
    $join .= $option . $a[1];

    return $join;
}
```

### Example

```
$a = pp_append_option_to_select('<option value="current">Current page</option>', $xml);

print_r($a);
```

Hoping someone finds this useful someday.

Am still open to better way of doing this using DomDocuement class.